# Finding Row with the column of Yes/No Type in jackcess

Tags: java, ms-access, jackcess

I am using jackess 2 for reading a Access file in Java. Below is the code.

In the table that I read, I have only 1 row. There is a column called "Active" of type "Yes/No" in MS-Access.

When I print all values in the table, the value of Active column is shown as "true". But when I try to query the row using findRow(), there is no match.

How can I query the table for the column "Active"?

```
try {
    Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File(strDataPath + "DB.mdb"));
    Table table = db.getTable("03_Test_Cases");

    for(Row row : table) {
        System.out.println("Column 'a' has value: " + row.get("Active"));
        // RETURNS "true"
    }

    Row row = CursorBuilder.findRow(table, Collections.singletonMap("Active", "true"));

    if(row != null) {
       System.out.println("Found row : " + row);
    } else {
       System.out.println("Could not find row"); // Always hits here only.
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: From an MS Access point of view, TRUE is equal to -1, it is not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the search value as an actual boolean value, not a string. This works for me:

```java
Row row = CursorBuilder.findRow(table, Collections.singletonMap("Active", true));
if (row != null) {
    System.out.println("Found row : " + row);
}
else {
    System.out.println("Could not find row");
}
```

Comment: Great.. I was trying in as "true" before. When I change it as per your suggestion, it works. Thanks.